# How to make something on startup in Eclipse E4 application?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to run something exactly after E4 RCP application starts.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `LifeCycle` class. You specify this in the `lifeCyceURI` property of your product:

```xml
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="%product.name"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     <property
           name="lifeCycleURI"
           value="bundleclass://plugin-id/package.LifeCycle">
     </property>
     ....
```

The `PostContextCreate` annotation runs very early in the startup:

```java
public class LifeCycle
{
  @PostContextCreate
  public void postContextCreate()
  {
  }
}
```

See [Register for the Eclipse 4 Application Life Cycle](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4LifeCycle/article.html)