# Custom Logging Console RCP e4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

my first question at stackoverflow :)
I've got a e4 rcp application and log like it is described in this tutorial: [Eclipse Logging](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseLogging/article.html)

```java
@Inject Logger logger; 
logger.error("Error: Closing application");
```

So for my application I want to show the log in a custom view, but I have no idea how to get the log output. Is there a way to add an listener or something to catch all log information and write it into text field?

So far thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own class extending `Logger` to do what you want. You then install that class in to the application context to replace the default. The best place to do this would be in the `@PostContextCreate` method of a `LifeCycle` class:

```java
@PostContextCreate
void postContextCreate(IEclipseContext context)
{
  Logger myClass = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyLoggerClass.class, context);

  context.set(Logger.class, myClass);
}
```

`LifeCycle` class is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703801/how-to-make-something-on-startup-in-eclipse-e4-application)

Comment: How to Implement a part in e4 which acts a Console like view and how to link it with the logger?

Comment: @RajPerumalsamy That is far too complex a question for a comment.